# Arms scrunch and lose volume when armature moves

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, weight-painting, vertex-weights

I have a simple humanoid armature: no IK rigging yet and it worked fine until the arms started messing up when I try to move them.  As far as I can tell there is nothing wrong with the weight painting, I even cleared all the weights off of all the vertex groups in the arms but when I repainted them the same thing happened.  The mesh doesn't follow the bones at the same speed and deforms wrong and I have no idea why or how to fix it.
[image: Unposed Armature]
[image: Armature Malfunction]

The only modifier I have active is the armature so its not a stack order problem, and none of the other bones have any weight on any part of the arm so I really just have no clue what is wrong here and any help would be *greatly* appreciated.

EDIT: Here is the .blend file

[image]

Comment: Maybe share the .blend? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Have you tried Weights -> Normalize All?

Comment: Normalize All doesn't fix it, sadly, just reduces the strength of most of my weights.

Answer (score 1):

Your arm is affected by two extra bones:

Spine.2

[image: Spine.2 weight paint]

Spine.1

[image: Spine.1 weight paint]

That's why your mesh only follows the arm at "one-third speed"; the other two-thirds of the influence comes from these two Spine bones.

If I quickly clean up the Spine bone's influence, the arm moves correctly.

[image: Fixed arm]

Btw, one quick way to check what bones influence a vert is to select the vert in Edit mode and look in the sidebar under the "Item" tab. You can see a list of all groups the vert is assigned to and their weights. See the extra Spine.1 and Spine.2?

[image: Sidebar showing vertex group elements]